# AND in SQL Left Join causes run-time error in Access 2010

Tags: sql, join, ms-access-2010

I appreciate any help you can give me.  I am trying to use a SQL query as the recordsource for a form.

```
strSQL = "SELECT " & DocID & " AS DocID,'" & DocumentType & "' AS DocumentType,"   & "B.Description AS [Decision Point], B.QCDecisionPointID,C.QCNote FROM ((QC.QCAttributeDecisionPointAsc A INNER JOIN QC.QCDecisionPoint B ON A.QCDecisionPointID = B.QCDecisionPointID) LEFT OUTER JOIN QC.QCResultDecisionPoint C ON C.QCDecisionPointID=B.QCDecisionPointID AND C.QCAssignmentID=" & AssignmentID & " ) WHERE QCAttributeID= " & AttributeID & ";"
```

But I am getting run-time errors for it as follows:
If I remove the parantheses in the sql string then : "Syntax error (mising operator) in query expression"

If I have parantheses in the query, then I get this error in Access:
"Join expression not supported"

I think it is the AND in the LEFT JOIN.  I need the query to be like this to get the right results, please show me how I can do this using a subquery.  The sql string I see when I debug is as follows:

```
SELECT 7674754 AS DocID,'All Supporting Documents' AS DocumentType,
B.Description AS [Decision Point], B.QCDecisionPointID,C.QCNote 
FROM QC.QCAttributeDecisionPointAsc A 
INNER JOIN QC.QCDecisionPoint B ON A.QCDecisionPointID = B.QCDecisionPointID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN QC.QCResultDecisionPoint C ON C.QCDecisionPointID=B.QCDecisionPointID 
AND C.QCAssignmentID=53 WHERE A.QCAttributeID= 3;
```

Thank you for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving `AND C.QCAssignmentID=53` into the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT 7674754 AS DocID,'All Supporting Documents' AS DocumentType,
B.Description AS [Decision Point], B.QCDecisionPointID,C.QCNote 
FROM QC.QCAttributeDecisionPointAsc A 
INNER JOIN QC.QCDecisionPoint B ON A.QCDecisionPointID = B.QCDecisionPointID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN QC.QCResultDecisionPoint C ON C.QCDecisionPointID=B.QCDecisionPointID 
WHERE A.QCAttributeID= 3 AND (C.QCAssignmentID=53 OR C.QCAssignmentID IS NULL)
```

As it's a LEFT JOIN you will need to specify that you want a specific value from C or nothing (that's why `OR C.QCAssignmentID IS NULL` is there)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I wish I could post some images to explain the structure of my database and the results of the query.  But, putting this in the where clause causes only 5 of the 6 records to appear since one category has a note attached to it for AssignmentID=34

Comment: Thank you all so much for your help.  I think it is my database structure that is faulty...a query that retrieves simple data should not be this hard to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Please put the table names in square bracket as suggested by HansUp AND remove the round brackets in the condition section. Try this:

```
SELECT  7674754                    AS DocID
      , 'All Supporting Documents' AS DocumentType
      , B.Description              AS [Decision Point]
      , B.QCDecisionPointID
      , C.QCNote
FROM    [QC.QCAttributeDecisionPointAsc] A
        INNER JOIN [QC.QCDecisionPoint] B
        ON      A.QCDecisionPointID = B.QCDecisionPointID
        LEFT JOIN [QC.QCResultDecisionPoint] C
        ON      C.QCDecisionPointID = B.QCDecisionPointID
        AND     C.QCAssignmentID    = 53
WHERE   A.QCAttributeID             = 3;
```

Comment: I am getting this error : Syntax error (missin goperator) in query expression

Answer (score 0):

That is correct, you cannot use AND in a join as you show it. Will you get the answer you need with And in the Where statement? Note also that Access requires parentheses around Joins when there is more than one.

```
SELECT  7674754                    AS DocID
      , 'All Supporting Documents' AS DocumentType
      , B.Description              AS [Decision Point]
      , B.QCDecisionPointID
      , C.QCNote
FROM  (  [QC.QCAttributeDecisionPointAsc] A
        INNER JOIN [QC.QCDecisionPoint] B
        ON      A.QCDecisionPointID = B.QCDecisionPointID )
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM [QC.QCResultDecisionPoint] 
                   WHERE QCAssignmentID    = 53) As C
ON      C.QCDecisionPointID = B.QCDecisionPointID
WHERE   A.QCAttributeID             = 3
```

Comment: The where clause can be part of a subquery.